# Limiting the Value of an input in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm creating the following web app for my employer:

https://jsfiddle.net/kupe2rLL/3/

**How it Works**: The **Missed Opportunity** and **Engage Results** fields populate dynamically as users enter information in the **Company Info** section.

**The Problem**: I need to program the app so that the **Years in Business** input takes no value **less than 1** and no value **greater than three** when calculating the **jobsRecovered** variable and **RevenueYear** variable only.

```
<input type="text" id="yearsOpen" name="yearsOpen" class="form-control" onchange="calculateAll()" required>                     

var jobsRecovered = (averageJobs * 50) * recovery * yearsOpen;
var revenueYear = jobsRecovered * jobValue;
```

Preferably, I need the **Years in Business** input field to accept any value from **0 to infinity** on the form input but then change the value of that variable to a **minimum of 1** and **maximum of 3** when making calculations for the **jobsRecovered** variable and **RevenueYear** only. I'd like to implement this solution using a JavaScript function if possible but I am open to alternate solutions.

I researched and implemented the following solution but unfortunately this only limits the min - max range of input on the form itself:

```
input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var num = parseInt(this.value, 10),
    min = 1,
    max = 3;

    if (isNaN(num)) {
        this.value = "";
        return;
    }

    this.value = Math.max(num, min);
    this.value = Math.min(num, max);
});
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. (Note: My experience with programming is Beginner level.)

Comment: Your code seems fine for the front-end. What are you using for your backend?

Comment: I am trying to use JavaScript to implement this fix behind the scenes, I'd like to avoid having to use PHP or other true back-end languages if possible. Sorry I may have not used the correct jargon in my explanation.

Comment: don't forget to use var to declare min and max.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking, as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. As far as I can tell, you should not rely on the front end safety of data. (Supposing PHP for instance), the back end should then collect the `$_REQUEST`, parse, handle parsing issues, then alter value to fit within limits

Comment: @JavierCortez Then you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to solve this problem. If you need this logic to happen on the backend then you need to write backend code to do it. It is absolutely, positively, 100% impossible for you to write JavaScript that affects your backend (unless the backend is written with Node.js). You may as well be asking how to pick up a rock on Pluto from Earth without sending a robot. To verify data on the backend, you **must** write backend code. No way around it.

Comment: @Bonatti and Mike, noted and thanks for the feedback. I will research PHP soluitons in the meanwhile and have re-phrased the question slightly to improve the likelihood of getting more answers as you suggested.

Comment: I agree with the above comments, unless you have a node.js backend you can't use javascript to do what you want. And even then your front-end and backend code will still be separate things. For a good user-experience, front-end validation is nice because they don't have to post back in order to check the result. BUT - a malicious user can easily bypass any front-end validation you write. So if you value the integrity of your data you should always check it for validity on the back-end as well.

Comment: @JavierCortez As for your update, it doesn't look like you're updating `jobsRecovered` or `revenueYear` after setting the value of the input field. You need to update those variables and any fields that rely on them.

Comment: @JavierCortez never ever trust user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit the range of the variable value, you can pass it through if-else statements, or a ternary operation which act like a **filter** for your values.
e.g.

```
if (yearsOpen <= 3) ? (if (yearsOpen < 1) ? (yearsOpen = 1) : (yearsOpen = yearsOpen)) : (yearsOpen = 3);
```

smaller statement `if (n <= 3) ? (if (n < 1) ? (n = 1) : (n = n)) : (n = 3);`

If-else format:

```
if (yearsOpen <= 3) {
    if (yearsOpen < 1) {
        yearsOpen = 1;
    } else {
        yearsOpen = yearsOpen;
    }
} else {
    yearsOpen = 3;
}
```

Hope that makes sense.